# Help me to sketch this parametric curves

Tags: parametric

Is there any defined process to sketch parametric curves?
Thanks in advance.

$$x = \cos^2 t, \quad y = 1 - \sin t, \quad 0 \leq t  \leq 2\pi.$$

Comment: *Hint*: try to compute $y^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
x=\cos^2(t)\\1-x=\sin^2(t)\\\sqrt{1-x}=\sin(t)\\1-\sqrt{1-x}=1-\sin(t)=y\\
y=1-\sqrt{1-x}\\
(1-x)=(1-y)^2
\end{align}

Comment: is there any defined method to do that?

Comment: Be careful: $\sqrt{1-x}=\sqrt{\sin^2(t)}=|\sin(t)|$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the animated curve. Note that it is periodic. [image: gif]

Comment: I understand Sigur, very illustrative. What software did you use?

Comment: GeoGebra www.geogebra.org

Answer (score 1):

You can use the identity $\cos^2t + \sin^2t = 1$. Then $\sin^2t = 1 - \cos^2t$, so $\sin t = \pm \sqrt{1 - x}$. Then you can plug this into the equation for $y$ and sketch the curve.